# How to check whether the database is closed in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
db_conn = connections['default']
try:
    c = db_conn.cursor()
except OperationalError:
    connected = False
else:
    connected = True
```

In server I have not close the connection but unable to update the query it shows the db connection is closed. Is there any solution in django to check whether the database is closed

Comment: Could you show the full error message you have? You do not need to check the state of db connection normally

Comment: @Lucas Grugru Unable to insert into the table : (0, '') ... This is an exception

Comment: Django provides a way to check whether a database connection is closed. The connection.ensure_connection() method ensures that a database connection is established and not closed.